# How to import export Azure Cosmos DB sore procedure from One resource group to another

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cosmosdb

I want to copy Store procedure from one resource group to another. Is there any way by which I can achieve this task.

I have two resource group **develop** and **production**.

I have tried Azure storage Explorer to do this task like It supports the table movement from one resource group to another but didn't work out.

Any help will be appriciable.

Comment: Any updates now? Does my answer helps you?

Comment: @JayGong : I am looking for some automated approach. Like import or export or some Azure Powershell script.

Comment: No such scripts are found.Stored procedure hangs under collection, you can't copy them alone to other collection.

Answer (score 0):

Azure cosmos db stored procedure subordinates to the `collection` level. There is no tool to support the direct bulk migration of stored procedure to other databases. It's completely different from `Table`.

I suggest using Azure cosmos db sdk to query all your stored procedures to get the `body` ,then insert into your target collection one by one in loop.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I am still stuck on this particular issue. If any code sample is available to query the store procedure from one Resource group and post into another will be helpful.